# automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets doesn't work in iOS9

Tags: uikit, ios9

In my app I have lots of VCs with scrollviews of all kinds (table, collection, etc.). All of them appear inside NavigationController and I used `.automaticallyadjustsscrollviewinsets` property of VC to prevent content from going under the NavigationBar. It works fine prior to iOS9.

I've updated my test iPhone to iOS9 yesterday and noticed that all scrollviews now does not have proper insets. I've updated XCode to latest version (7.0) and rebuilt the app - no effect. I've checked on the other device, which is still running iOS8.x - insets work correctly. I looked through iOS9 sdk changelogs and didn't find anything related to my problem. Is this a bug or a new behaviour? Anyone else having this problem? Possible solutions?

**UPDATE1**

I've came up with quick fix:

```
if (__iOS_9_OR_GREATER__) {

    CGFloat topInset = 20;

    if (self.navigationController) {
        topInset += self.navigationController.navigationBar.bounds.size.height;
    }

    UIEdgeInsets insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(topInset, 0, 0, 0);

    self.collectionView.contentInset = insets;
    self.collectionView.scrollIndicatorInsets = insets;

}
```

It works. But question is still relevant, is this a bug in iOS9?

**UPDATE2**

Answering the question in the comments about `__iOS_9_OR_GREATER__`. Probably not the most efficient solution, but gets the job done.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#define __iOS_9_OR_GREATER__ [NKOSVersionCheck isMajorOSVersionAtLeast:9]

@interface NKOSVersionCheck : NSObject

+ (BOOL)isMajorOSVersionAtLeast:(NSUInteger)version;

@end

#import "NKOSVersionCheck.h"

@implementation NKOSVersionCheck

NSOperatingSystemVersion _majorOSVersion(int version) {

    NSOperatingSystemVersion iOS_x;
    iOS_x.majorVersion = version;
    iOS_x.minorVersion = 0;
    iOS_x.patchVersion = 0;

    return iOS_x;

}

+ (BOOL)isMajorOSVersionAtLeast:(NSUInteger)version {

    return [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] isOperatingSystemAtLeastVersion:_majorOSVersion(9)];

}


@end
```

Comment: did u try setting .automaticallyadjustsscrollviewinsets to No ?

Comment: @DheerajSingh yes. ScrollView starts to go under nav bar on iOS8, and nothing changes on iOS9.

Comment: @NKorotkov What did you use to determine __iOS_9_OR_GREATER_

Comment: @NickWargnier I updated my question with the definition of `__iOS_9_OR_GREATER_`

Answer (score 2):

Since iOS9 `automaticallyadjustsscrollviewinsets` will not change `UIScrollView`'s `contentInsets` if it's created programmatically.

- a) You can use `UITableViewController` for auto adjustments.
- b) Set `automaticallyadjustsscrollviewinsets` and adjust insets by yourself.

Comment: a) `UITableViewController` is not an option in my case, since it complicates the view hierarchy. `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` has been set in storyboards, doesn't work in iOS9. b) yeah, I've pretty much went with manual solution. But why did they change that in first place? It used to work perfectly.

Comment: @NKorotkov you should add scroll views in storyboards, not only set this bool property.

Comment: I did. My TableViews and CollectionViews are added via storyboards.

Comment: @TimurBernikowich this is from your observation or does Apple has state this in their changelog? Could you provide me a link if it is a later case?

Comment: @sarunw this is from my observation. But there is a couple of links across the Internet: http://www.openradar.me/22106545

Comment: Rather than being a matter of adding the view programmatically I believe the problem is to do with the `UIScrollView` not being the root view of the ViewController. If you set the class of the root `View` in Interface Builder to `UIScrollView` it will work, otherwise it will not. I assume it would also work to programmatically replace the root view of a ViewController with a `UIScrollView`.