# WebView content not scaling correctly

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I am trying to load some content in a UIWebView, but it is not showing correctly.
I drew a red edge around the webview, and it is correctly positioned. But as you can see, the content has a grey bar above it.

[image: Arghh webviews]

I have the following code in my viewDidLoad the webview:

```
productEnergyDetailWebview = [[UIWebView alloc]init];
productEnergyDetailWebview.delegate = self;
productEnergyDetailWebview.scalesPageToFit = YES;
productEnergyDetailWebview.opaque = YES;
[productEnergyDetailWebview setUserInteractionEnabled:true];
productEnergyDetailWebview.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
productEnergyDetailWebview.scrollView.bounces = false;
productEnergyDetailWebview.scrollView.scrollEnabled = false;
```

More code:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [topBar removeFromSuperview];
    [self createViews];
    [productEnergyDetailWebview setScalesPageToFit:YES];
    [refreshIndicator stopAnimating];
    [refreshIndicator removeFromSuperview];
    [productEnergyDetailWebview setHidden:false];
}





-(void)createViews{
        productEnergyDetailWebview.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
        if(selectedRange != 5 && selectedRange != 4){
            //Add the bar above the detailWebView
            [self createTopBar];
            int xLocation = topBar.frame.size.height + topBar.frame.origin.y;
                [productEnergyDetailWebview setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, xLocation, self.view.frame.size.width, (self.view.frame.size.height - xLocation) - 50)];
                [productEnergyDetailWebview setScalesPageToFit:YES];
                [productEnergyDetailWebview setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
            }

        productEnergyDetailWebview.scrollView.bounces = false;
        productEnergyDetailWebview.scrollView.scrollEnabled = false;
        [productEnergyDetailWebview setUserInteractionEnabled:true];

    }
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong in this case? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

on your `viewDidLoad`

Edit:

The answer above doesn't work on iOS9

This [solution from NKorotkov](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32650109/automaticallyadjustsscrollviewinsets-doesnt-work-in-ios9) works:

```
if (__iOS_9_OR_GREATER__) {

    CGFloat topInset = 20;

    if (self.navigationController) {
        topInset += self.navigationController.navigationBar.bounds.size.height;
    }

    UIEdgeInsets insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(topInset, 0, 0, 0);

    self.collectionView.contentInset = insets;
    self.collectionView.scrollIndicatorInsets = insets;

}
```

Comment: Sadly this didn't help

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32650109/automaticallyadjustsscrollviewinsets-doesnt-work-in-ios9) may help you

Comment: Yes it did, if you edit your answer I will accept it!